# Magento 2.4.6-p3 attributes names as html text on page

Tags: magento2.4.6

After update to 2.4.6-p3 i see unnecessary HTML elements on the page, as if they were attributes.
I has all custom modules completely disabled, and of course i haven't forgotten about bin/magento se:up etc - the problem remains.
This strange behavior has only been seen on one website.
What could be the reason?
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: it seems in loop, Added echo for attribute code! may be for testing purpose

Comment: yes, i found on server 2 modified files:
1. vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php.
2. vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
I don't know who modified it. 
But Mysql.php has been to original state rewrite, and in AbstactCollection.php 
one line was added:
echo PHP_EOL.$attribute;
I passed this Infos to security team.